# how to redirect login page in yii if user is not log in?

Tags: redirect, yii

how to check on each page user is logged or not if user is not logged in it must be redirect to login page.
In order to access any page user must perform authentication .

Answer (score 1):

Yii provides accesscontrol for actions ,here is example . try this ,if Guest user try to access these actions , they will be redirected to login page

```
    class ExampleController extends Controller {
        /**
         * @return array action filters
         */
        public function filters() {
            return array(
                'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            );
        }

        /**
         * Specifies the access control rules.
         * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
         * @return array access control rules
         */
        public function accessRules() {
            return array(

                array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform these actions
                    'actions' => array('create','delete'),  // add the actions need authuentication
                    'users' => array('@'),
                ),                
            );
        }    
    }
```

Comment: i think this would work under ExampleController. i want that if user type any url , must redirect to the login page only authorized user can access page or perform any operation

Comment: ok. your all  controllers inherit  // extends Controller {//  , write this two function there . hope this works

Comment: currently im using this code  public function beforeAction($action)
 {
  if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
  {
   
   
   $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('user/login/login')); 
   
   return true;
  }
  else
  { 
    return true;
  }
 
  //something code right here if user valided
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 0):

add this funtion in every controller.

```
public function beforeAction($action) {

if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest && Yii::app()->controller->action->id != "login") {
    Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
}
//something code right here if user valid
return true;  
}
```

site controller only needs `Yii::app()->controller->action->id != "login"` this condition. remove it for other controllers.